# Why can't I assign a canvas-object to an existing canvas?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas

My software creates rather complex petrinets that will be drawn on a canvas. Since this is shown multiple times (a preview window, a larger view, …) I would like to cache the drawn canvas. 
My first try was

XAML:

```
<Canvas Name="MyCanvas" />
```

Code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Canvas NewCanvas = new Canvas();
    TextBlock txt1 = new TextBlock();
    txt1.Text = "Hello World!";
    Canvas.SetTop(txt1, 10);
    Canvas.SetLeft(txt1, 10);
    NewCanvas.Children.Add(txt1);

    MyCanvas = NewCanvas;
}
```

But that does not show anything at all. I can, however replace the last line with

```
MyCanvas.Children.Add(NewCanvas);
```

Now I can see my canvas, BUT if I try to open another window showing the same canvas

```
Window NewWindow = new Window();
NewWindow.Content = NewCanvas;
NewWindow.Show();
```

I get an System.ArgumentException:

> “Must disconnect specified child from current parent Visual before
>   attaching to new parent Visual.”

I looked into cloning the canvas-object, but the canvas-object is not serializable, and XamlWriter needs a special contructor in the custom-written UIElements-classes, but I don't have a clue what exactly it needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first look at your errors so you get a better understanding for what the code does:

```
MyCanvas = NewCanvas;
```

This does not do what you want because you simply replace the reference. `MyCanvas` is a variable in your instance that at first points to a `Canvas` instance (the empty instance that is shown in your form). When you execute the above statement, the `MyCanvas` variable is modified to reference another `Canvas` instance - a `Canvas` instance that may contain some graphical elements, but that is at no point added to your window. Your window continues to just contain the original, empty `Canvas` instance.

The `System.ArgumentException` occurs exactly because of what it says. You cannot add a visual element to several parents at a time.

---

The cleaner solution would be not to duplicate the complete `Canvas`, but to have a method (or an object with a method) that takes a `Canvas` as a parameter and then creates and adds all the elements your petrinet comprises of to the `Canvas`. In a very simplified form like this:

```
public class Petrinet
{
    public void OutputPetrinet(Canvas dest)
    {
        if (dest == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dest");
        }

        Ellipse e = new Ellipse() {
            Width = 50,
            Height = 60,
            Fill = Brushes.Blue
        };
        Canvas.SetLeft(e, 20);
        Canvas.SetTop(e, 30);
        dest.Children.Add(e);
    }
}
```

You can then invoke this method for as many `Canvas` instances as you like.

Note that you can also use that `Petrinet` class to store the data that describes your petrinets - *and* you can make that class serializable so you can persist that data, as it's your own class :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want. As your `Exception` told you, In WPF each UI element can only be hosted in the visual tree just once. Basically, that means that if a UI element is being displayed in the UI then you cannot add that same UI element into another container in the UI. You could remove a UI element from its current location and then add it to a different container in the UI, but that is not what you want.

Just to be clear, I'm talking about UI elements, not data elements. One data element can be represented in the UI many times and although its rendered forms may all look exactly the same, they will actually all be different UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
*`I get an System.ArgumentException: “Must disconnect specified child from current parent Visual before attaching to new parent Visual.”`*
```

In Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), an element can have no more than one visual parent and no more than one logical parent. This is actually very important because it ensures that the visual and logical trees are well-formed.

*`But that does not show anything at all. I can, however replace the last line with`*
this  normal  you are creating a new object and you should add it to your logical tree in  order to let wpf do all the required calculations 
for example you can do something like this

```
        this.yourGrid.Children.Add(NewCanvas);
```

*`I looked into cloning the canvas-object, but the canvas-object is not serializable`*

you can't serialize your control  as you are doing  you can use something like this

```
        string saved = XamlWriter.Save(canvas1); 
        StringReader sReader = new StringReader(saved); 
        XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader); 
        Canvas newCanvas = (Canvas)XamlReader.Load(xReader); 
        yourGrid.Children.Add(newCanvas);
```